# Create custom login system with FormsAuthentication and more in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, login-system

Sorry for the big title.

So I've been doing some research for making login systems. I've already made my own, but discovered a more secure way to do it.
As far as I know, the four basic components of this login system are:

- FormsAuthentication
- MembershipProvider
- RoleProvider
- Principal

I have this as my basic user model:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

This is just for retaining the data from the database.

I still want to use this model with the components listed above.

Does anyone know a good and thorough tutorial that explains how to create a custom login system using the above components in MVC 3 Razor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a custom 'login system' by implementing a custom version of `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` that uses your own database.  Then you can re-use all the rest of the built in authentication and authorization stuff.

MSDN has some details on how to build a `MembershipProvider` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e) and details on a custom `RoleProvider` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx).  Samples implementations are included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this open source project :

https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit